# Typescript with jQuery UI Widgets - Implementing call signatures

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, typescript

I have many dialogs throughout my website (Login dialog, Register dialog, Contact dialog, etc) that I am trying to model using Typescript.

the jquery-ui d.ts file defines a Dialog interface as such:

```
interface Dialog extends Widget, DialogOptions, DialogEvents{  }
```

Everything in `DialogOptions` and `DialogEvents` is optional so no problems there, but the Widget interface defines some call signatures that I am not understanding:

```
interface Widget {
    (methodName: string): JQuery;
    (options: WidgetOptions): JQuery;
    (options: AccordionOptions): JQuery;
    (optionLiteral: string, optionName: string): any;
    (optionLiteral: string, options: WidgetOptions): any;
    (optionLiteral: string, optionName: string, optionValue: any): JQuery;

    (name: string, prototype: any): JQuery;
    (name: string, base: Function, prototype: any): JQuery;
}
```

When I try to implement this interface in a class:

```
class LoginDialog implements Dialog { 

}
```

The compiler complains:

```
Class 'LoginDialog' declares interface 'Dialog' but does not implement it: Type 'Dialog' requires a call signature, but Type 'LoginDialog' lacks one.
```

I don't understand how to implement these "call signatures" or what they should do, in fact, I don't even understand what a call signature is.

EDIT:

I found one type of valid use case for a call signature is for call back typing:

```
interface ICallback{
    (param: string) : void;
}

function someMethod(callback: ICallback){
    callback('a string'); //Good
    callback(5);         //Bad 
}
```

However, the question still stands as I could not find a use case for multiple call signatures and still don't understand how to implement the jquery-ui.d.ts Dialog interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI, you don't need to implement any of these interfaces as they are already implemented in jQuery UI. These interfaces simply give you type information to use to call the existing jQuery UI functions with static typing.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
```

Without the `jquery-ui.d.ts` the type system wouldn't know about the `dialog()` function, for example.

Comment: Well yes that's how I currently use dialogs, no problem there. But I was hoping to accomplish a more object oriented approach to managing the many dialogs on my site which differ only slightly. I don't have the code in front of me right now but I will look into this more later when I do.

Comment: In that case I would hide the entire jQuery implementation behind your own IDialog interface, so your own interface is simpler.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, question answered. Thanks